# How should we put two lens?

Tags: optics, lenses

How should we put two converging lens in order for parallel rays passing between both lens to remain parallel?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to know, given a point source as input where should you put a thin lens to produce parallel rays as output?

Comment: Perhaps he means something like this: <()====()>

Comment: Lets say you have air, does light ray bend any where? No, it won't, until it encounters another medium of different refractive index. Similarly, if you want the ray to travel as it is, with out facing the bending, then you need arrange the apparatus in such a way that the portion of ray encounters same lens medium while it travels through two lens. Now its up to you to think.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is known as a telescope. The distance between the two lenses should be the sum of their focal length.